# why is my second to last number not visible in output?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When running

```
>>> a = np.linspace(0, 330, 330, 1, dtype=int)
>>> print(a)


[  0,   1,   2, ..[skipped for readability].. 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330])], dtype=int
```

I expect the second last number to be `329` instead of `328`. Why is this not the case? It's probably because that number in a float will be `328.99696049` but I do wonder how I can include it into my output, and if it does matter for my data purity when I do calculations on that number.

Comment: What is your code that generates your array? What do you expect the 2nd last value to be? A float?

Comment: >>> a = np.linspace(0, 330, 330, 1, dtype=int)
    >>> print(a)

The missing number is 329

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is correct. [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) distributes `330` values between `0` and `330` which means the stepsize between two neighboring values is `(end - start) / (steps - 1) = 330 / 329`. Since you coerce to `int`, the decimal part is truncated.

If you would like a stepsize of `1` continously, you need `331` steps:

```
a = np.linspace(0, 330, 331, 1, dtype=int)
```

Of course it's even simpler to get the same result using [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
a = np.arange(331)
```